# split the arrays and get the column value from in rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have the following array list in my view. How can I use the array each loop and get the values from it?

```
  [#<Order::List code: 1511, Reference: "FRIA004", valuation: nil, full_Address: "1, abc road, xyz", reason_available: "Y", list: "1 : Meter cupboard generic throughout - Very low">,
     #<Order::List code: 1512, Reference: "FRIA005", valuation: nil, full_Address: "2, abc road, xyz", reason_available: "Y", list: "2 : Meter cupboard generic throughout - Very high">,
     #<Order::List code: 1513, Reference: "FRIA006", valuation: nil, full_Address: "3, abc road, xyz", reason_available: "Y", list: "15 : Meter cupboard generic throughout - Low">,
     #<Order::List code: 1514, Reference: "FRIA007", valuation: nil, full_Address: "6, abc road, xyz", reason_available: "Y", list: "16 : Meter cupboard generic throughout - High">]
```

### Expected output:

full_address

reason_available

list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets your array

```
@orders = [#<Order::List code: 1511, Reference: "FRIA004", valuation: nil, full_Address: "1, abc road, xyz", reason_available: "Y", list: "1 : Meter cupboard generic throughout - Very low">,
     #<Order::List code: 1512, Reference: "FRIA005", valuation: nil, full_Address: "2, abc road, xyz", reason_available: "Y", list: "2 : Meter cupboard generic throughout - Very high">,
     #<Order::List code: 1513, Reference: "FRIA006", valuation: nil, full_Address: "3, abc road, xyz", reason_available: "Y", list: "15 : Meter cupboard generic throughout - Low">,
     #<Order::List code: 1514, Reference: "FRIA007", valuation: nil, full_Address: "6, abc road, xyz", reason_available: "Y", list: "16 : Meter cupboard generic throughout - High">]
```

in view

```
  <ul>
     <% @orders.each do |order| %>
       <li><%= order.full_Address %></li>
       <li><%= order.reason_available %></li>
    <% end %>
   </ul>
```

Comment: Hi, I got undefined method for full_address. Thanks

Comment: The full address had comma inbetween the quotes... How can I get it? Thanks

Comment: what you want to get use split `order.full_address.split(",")` then it will show `["1", "abc road", "xyz"]` for this `1, abc road, xyz` full address if you want to remove the comma then `order.full_address.gsub(",",'')`

Comment: Thank you very much for helping. I got the problem to find the full_address. It's said undefined method. Any ideas please?

Comment: I have changed the post it should be `full_Address` as per your instance field not `full_address`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I marked as answered. One more question is it possible that I can list all the codes into an array in the view?

Comment: yes In view  `<%= @orders.collect(&:full_Address) %>`